# Devise:Invitable redirecting me to sign_in

Tags: devise, devise-invitable

<%= link_to "Invite Admin", new_admin_invitation_path, method: :get, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm me-2' %>

when i click on this button i am redirecting to the sign in page and getting 401 Unauthorized error in logs.

anyone please help!